How to Handle back button in Flutter web when Popscope is not working?
There are 4 different pages in my app. Users can navigate like this:
P1 -> P2 -> P3 -> P4.
Popscope is implemented in every screen, but the problem is when users want to back two screens (P4 to P2), app gets terminated. This problem just happens in web on google Chrome.
In P4 everything is normal, after tapping on chrome's back button P4 gets poped out and P3 comes in front.

When P3 comes on top back button gets disabled until user tap anywhere in the app, otherwise app gets terminated after tapping on back button.

Flutter version : 3.22.2
channel stable
What should I do to overcome this problem?
BTW it's working fine on firefox.
